# Collect dump using dotnet monitor without restarting pod

Tags: asp.net-core, kubernetes, monitoring, .net-6.0

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to attach `dotnet-monitor` as a sidecar to a running .NET 6 pod in Kubernetes, so that a dump can be collected, without restarting the monitored pod?

My use case is that we have some very rare issues where we'd like to take a process dump, but if we configure dotnet-monitor according to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-monitor/blob/main/documentation/kubernetes.md), then the pod will be restarted (and the issue is resolved). Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like use case for [ephemeral containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/ephemeral-containers/)

> Ephemeral containers are useful for interactive troubleshooting when
> kubectl exec is insufficient because a container has crashed or a
> container image doesn't include debugging utilities

See also [Debugging with an ephemeral debug container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-running-pod/#ephemeral-container)